# System of differential equations with initial condition. How is initial condition 'intended' here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, systems-of-equations, brownian-motion, initial-value-problems

Starting from the following differential equation
\begin{equation}
dS=aSdt+\sqrt{S}dW \tag{1}
\end{equation}
with $dW$ denoting Wiener increment, if one splits the above SDE $(1)$ into stochastic part and deterministic part as follows
$$
dS_1=\sqrt{S}dW\tag{2}$$$$dS_2=aS dt\tag{3}
$$
in which sense am I given that *"the numerical solution to $(2)$ is used as the initial condition in $(3)$, with the solution to $(3)$ providing the approximation to the true solution at each timestep"*?

---

I used to consider a typical initial condition differential equation as follows for example
$$dS=aSdt + \sqrt{S}dW\\S(0)=0.43$$
How can the above example typical scheme be applied to the above mentioned system? That is, let us pretend that I am able to find a numerical solution to $(2)$. Then? What I do with such a solution so as to solve $(3)$, or, better, in which sense does solution to $(2)$ represent the initial condition to $(3)$?

Comment: You can apply numerical solution  for $\begin{equation}
dS=aSdt+\sqrt{S}dW \tag{1}
\end{equation}$ ,for example euler-maryuma scheme...no need to solve it by system of equation.

Comment: Yeah, of course, but I am given the "splitted" version (in the form of the above system) and I would like to understand how the splitted version works @Khosrotash

Comment: $dW$ can be $\sqrt{\Delta t}\times rand$

Answer (score 1):

I suggest away, but honestly, I did not use it.

rewrite it as $$\begin{equation}
dS_1=0dt+\sqrt{S}dW\\
dS_2=asdt+0dW\\
s(0)=0.43,W(0)=0
\end{equation}$$ and turn it to matrix form
$$d\begin{bmatrix}S_1 \\S_2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \sqrt s \\as & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}dW \\ds \end{bmatrix}$$ hope it will helpful